# Pycharm does not detect IPython

Tags: ipython, pycharm, anaconda

Is IPython 5 supported in Pycharms?

This line works fine on Spyder (packaged with Anacoda)

```
IPython.display.Audio(wv_array)
```

On Pycharms it throws an attribute exception:

> AttributeError: module 'IPython' has no attribute 'display'

Must mention I've been unable to configure IPython console from Pycharms.

> Python: 3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)
>
> Pycharms: 2017.2
>
> IPython: 5.1.0

Comment: Not sure if this issue has been resolved, but I am adding my input here in case we can learn from each other. I am using PyCharm **2017.1** community edition on Mac. It works with IPython 5.1.0. But I am having issues with the IPython console in PyCharm on Linux.